# JQuery Autocomplete. Как выделить совпадения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Встала задача сделать поисковик по dropdown. Решил реализовать на jquery. Взял готовый пример с [официального сайта](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Единственное, что меня не устроило - это то, что совпадения в тексте не выделяются жирным шрифтом. Я изменил код так, чтобы совпадения брались в теги `<strong>...</strong>`.

***Подробнее о проблематике***: мне нужно жирным выделять буквы и цифры, которые совпадают с критерием поиска. Например, я ввожу **asi** или **avascr** и в *dropdown menu* текст должен иметь такой вид: B**ASI**C или J**avaScr**ipt соответственно.

Однако, теги не заменяются на стили. Может кто знает, как это исправить?

---

```js
$( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            classes: {
              "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
            }
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .on( "mousedown", function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .on( "click", function() {
            input.trigger( "focus" );
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "gi");
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(matcher, function(str) {
                return '<strong>' + str + '</strong>'
            });
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
 
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

P.S. Проблема связана с тем, что **strong**'и при вставке преобразуются в текст, а не в теги. Так можно заметить, что внешний вид текст в исходном коде имеет следующий вид:

```
<div id="ui-id-123" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">&lt;strong&gt;As&lt;/strong&gt;p</div>
```

вместо

```
<div id="ui-id-123" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><strong>As</strong>p</div>
```

Это и вызывает проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1** - *решение с минимумом изменений Вашего кода:*

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
      this.wrapper = $("<span>")
        .addClass("custom-combobox")
        .insertAfter(this.element);

      this.element.hide();
      this._createAutocomplete();
      this._createShowAllButton();
    },

    _createAutocomplete: function() {
      var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

      this.input = $("<input>")
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .val(value)
        .attr("title", "")
        .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
        .autocomplete({
          delay: 0,
          minLength: 0,
          source: $.proxy(this, "_source"),
          create: function() {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
              return $("<li>")
                .append('<div>' + item.label + '</div>')
                .appendTo(ul);
            }
          }
        })
        .tooltip({
          classes: {
            "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
          }
        });

      this._on(this.input, {
        autocompleteselect: function(event, ui) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          this._trigger("select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },

        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
      });
    },

    _createShowAllButton: function() {
      var input = this.input,
        wasOpen = false;

      $("<a>")
        .attr("tabIndex", -1)
        .attr("title", "Show All Items")
        .tooltip()
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .button({
          icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
          },
          text: false
        })
        .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
        .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
        .on("mousedown", function() {
          wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
        })
        .on("click", function() {
          input.trigger("focus");

          // Close if already visible
          if (wasOpen) {
            return;
          }

          // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
          input.autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    },

    _source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "gi");
      response(this.element.children("option").map(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(matcher, '<strong>$&</strong>');
        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
          return {
            label: text,
            value: text,
            option: this
          };
      }));
    },

    _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {

      // Selected an item, nothing to do
      if (ui.item) {
        return;
      }

      // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
      var value = this.input.val(),
        valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
        valid = false;
      this.element.children("option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
          this.selected = valid = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // Found a match, nothing to do
      if (valid) {
        return;
      }

      // Remove invalid value
      this.input
        .val("")
        .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
        .tooltip("open");
      this.element.val("");
      this._delay(function() {
        this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
      }, 2500);
      this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
    },

    _destroy: function() {
      this.wrapper.remove();
      this.element.show();
    }
  });

  $("#combobox").combobox();
  $("#toggle").on("click", function() {
    $("#combobox").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
        <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
        <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="C++">C++</option>
        <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
        <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
        <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
        <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
        <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
        <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
        <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
        <option value="Java">Java</option>
        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
        <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
        <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
        <option value="Python">Python</option>
        <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
        <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
        <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2** - *идея изменения стиля текста всего меню предлагаемая ранее:*

**Вариант 2.1** - *самый короткий и может не самый красивый*

```
.ui-menu-item{
font-weight: bold
}
```

```js
$( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            classes: {
              "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
            }
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .on( "mousedown", function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .on( "click", function() {
            input.trigger( "focus" );
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "gi");
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(matcher, function(str) {
                return str 
            });
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
 
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  } );
```

```css
.ui-menu-item{
font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2.2** - *можно посмотреть разные темы оформления*

У Вас `base` сейчас:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

На данный момент темы для [jQuery UI 1.12](http://code.jquery.com/ui/)
(- base 
- black-tie 
- blitzer 
- cupertino 
- dark-hive 
- dot-luv 
- eggplant 
- excite-bike 
- flick 
- hot-sneaks 
- humanity 
- le-frog 
- mint-choc 
- overcast 
- pepper-grinder
- redmond 
- smoothness 
- south-street 
- start sunny 
- swanky-purse 
- trontastic 
- ui-darkness 
- ui-lightness 
- vader)

**Вариант 2.3** - cами разработчики рекомендуют использовать CSS, это протестированный и отлаженный метод.
[Официальный сайт jquery-ui](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/theming/).

Коротко основное:

- Использовать [дизайнер стилей](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/themeroller/)
- Изменить файл CSS `jquery-ui.theme.css`
- Написать собственный файл

---

**Updated:** после уточнения вопроса ответ был дополнен.

---

Вы, кстати, очень близки были к одному из рабочих вариантов, потому как на официальном сайте нужный Вам  `Extension Points` [_renderItem( ul, item )](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) виджета `Autocomplete Widget` разбирался как раз в следующем пункте примеров [Custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)
Применим этот способ только при создании меню

P.S.: для справки привожу пример (тут товарищ свою библиотеку написал, возможно пригодится для размышлений):

> EasyAutocomplete is a highly configurable jquery autocomplete plugin. 
>   [GitHub](https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete)
>   [Сайт проекта](http://easyautocomplete.com/)

Comment: Всё не то. Ваши варианты работают со стилями, но проблемы не в них. Проблема в том, что теги `<strong></strong>` помещаются не как теги, а заменяются на текстовые символы. Из-за этого, при вводе текста в поле strong'и остаются.

Comment: в вопросе не было условия, что CSS нельзя использовать... проблема есть, но сами разработчики JQuery рекомендуют CSS. Обновлю ответ. А над вашим обновлённым вопросом еще подумаем

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что мне нужно жирным выделять не весь текст, а только буквы, которые совпадают с критерием поиска. Например, я ввожу **asi** и в *dropdown menu* текст должен иметь такой вид: B**ASI**C. Я не против использовать css, но проблему это не решит. Возможно, придётся искать другие библиотеки, использующие jquery. Благо, таких хватает.

Comment: да, ок, я подумаю еще, вопрос открыт.. откорректируйте вопрос пожалуйста, кстати в ранних версиях примеров что-то было.. такое про отличающуюся заглавную букву.. может найду готовое чтоб не мудрить

Comment: поставьте себя на место человека, которому нужно быстро получить ответ на свой вопрос. и тут он видит столько текста... Варианты 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 можно сжать до *Вариант 2 - `ui-menu-item`*, *Вариант 3 - `поменяйте или соберите тему ui`*.

Comment: @Akubik В общем, спасибо. Я хоть понимаю, в чём была моя ошибка. Всё равно тут остаются косяки в виде стронгов при выборе пункта. От них можно, разумеется, избавить, но я уже бросил идею. Сейчас использую selectize.js. Довольно не плохая библиотека. Взял её за основу - пофиксил некоторые вещи. В будущем планирую её дорабатывать по нуждам. Можете, кстати, её тоже в свой ответ добавить, как вариант. Тут есть ссылки на [GitHub](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) и [Demo](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/).